# Checking if a class has a copy ctor? return true or false

Tags: c++, sfinae

In below code snippet, I am trying to determine if a class has a copy ctor or not.
I will only see a compilation error if my class does not have a copy ctor. I could not make it to return true or false. Please help me with that ..

```
template <typename T>
auto has_copy_ctor(T const& data) -> decltype(T(data), bool())
{
    return true;
}

struct A
{
    A(A const& obj) = delete;
};

struct B {};

int main()
{
    std::cout << has_copy_ctor<B>(B{}) << std::endl; // compiles
    std::cout << has_copy_ctor<A>(A{}) << std::endl; // does not compile
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using [`std::is_copy_constructible`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_copy_constructible).

SFINAE means that a template failing to substitute is not an error, but you still have an error on your hands if no template matches. In your case, you'd need a second template function that returns false for classes that are not copy-constructible.

In libc++, `is_copy_constructible` is implemented using the `__is_constructible` non-standard compiler intrinsic. Since these are kept to a minimum, chances are that a "native C++" implementation would be non-trivial, if at all possible.

Comment: *"Since these are kept to a minimum, chances are that a "native C++" implementation would be non-trivial, if at all possible."*, [why not?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f66e255907a205c)

Comment: Well, I guess I'm not very imaginative.

Comment: Well I was more interested in knowing the else part of SFINAE, which I could not think of... I am still accepting your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can extend your approach (with a function template) to check whether a type is copy-constructible (in a world where `<type_traits>` are not available):

```
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
constexpr auto has_copy_ctor(int)
    -> decltype(T(std::declval<const T&>()), void(), bool())
{
    return true;
}

template <typename T>
constexpr bool has_copy_ctor(char)
{
    return false;
}

template <typename T>
constexpr bool has_copy_ctor()
{
    return has_copy_ctor<T>(0);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f66e255907a205c)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`std::is_copy_constructible`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_copy_constructible)

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << std::is_copy_constructible<B>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_copy_constructible<A>::value << std::endl;
}
```